# How to enable syslog on AIX?

Tags: aix, syslog

I'm trying to enable syslog on AIX. I followed the instructions [in this post](http://unixfoo.blogspot.ca/2008/11/aix-syslog.html) but it didn't work.

This is my /etc/syslog.conf:

```
mail.debug      /var/log/mail.log   rotate size 500k files 10
kern.debug      /var/log/kern.log   rotate size 500k files 10
syslog.debug    /var/log/syslog.log rotate size 500k files 10
daemon.debug    /var/log/daemon.log rotate size 500k files 10
local2.debug    /var/log/sudo.log   rotate size 500k files 10
```

I executed this:

```
refresh -s syslogd
```

But nothing is showing up in /var/log

I'm on AIX 6.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syslog files must exist before syslogd will write to them.  You will need to touch (as root) the filenames you wish to use first.

> touch /var/log/mail.log
>
> touch /var/log/kern.log
>
> ...etc

and then refresh syslog

Comment: you might want to add a `sudo` (as it is important that the files are owned by root) and add the command for "refreshing syslog").

Comment: I did say "as root", but you could also sudo.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send it to a syslog server as 192.168.1.1
you have to write like this in /etc/syslog.conf

```
user.info @192.168.1.1 rotate size 100k files 5
syslog.info @192.168.1.1 rotate size 100k files 5
auth.info @192.168.1.1 rotate size 100k files 5
local2.info @192.168.1.1 rotate size 100k files 5
```

after that don't forget to apply the changes using:

```
#refresh -s syslogd
```